# Update state dynamically with nested levels of objects and array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

This is the problem

I'm trying to update the state of this object called singleCarers

I have the index of the roster in the rosters array i need to update

but the The key monday: needs to be dynamic & the key start: & finish: also needs to dynamic

```
const indexOfRoster = index;

const dayOfRoster = day;

const { value, name } = e.target;  // name represents either start: or finish: & value is the value of start or finish eg. name:value === start: "09:10"
```

```
{
  "rosters": [
    {
       
        "schedule": {

            "monday": {

                "start": "",
                "finish": "",

            },
        },

    },
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You need reference the object using [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)
2. using a callback in set state requires you to return a new state from the function.

```js
setSingleCarers((prevState) => {
  const updatedRosters = prevState.rosters.map((roster, index) => (
    index === indexOfRoster
      ? {  // update the target roster
          ...roster,
          schedule: {
            ...roster.schedule,
            [dayOfRoster]: {
              ...roster.schedule[dayOfRoster],
              [name]: value,
            },
          },
        }
      : roster,
  ));

  return {  // return the new State
    ...prevState,
    rosters: updatedRosters,
  };
}
```

this may seem excessive in which case you can look into solutions like `immer` or other libraries that make this sort of object manipulation easier instead of having to remember to do deep object copying

Answer (score -1):

Do not over think it, if you don't use complex data types this is the best option

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`

```
const auxState = JSON.parse (JSON.stringify(reactState))

// now modify auxState
auxState[index][day]={
 start:"val",
 end:"val"
}

setReactState(auxState)
```

If you want to get fancy

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof (obj) !== 'object' || 'isActiveClone' in obj)
        return obj;

    if (obj instanceof Date)
        var temp = new obj.constructor(); //or new Date(obj);
    else
        var temp = obj.constructor();

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            obj['isActiveClone'] = null;
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
            delete obj['isActiveClone'];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

const auxState = clone(reactState)
// Modify auxState

setReactState (auxState)
```